# unicode time "data": "Reservation duration has to be positive."

Tags: python, datetime, unicode

I am passing some dummy parameters via HHTP client postman like so:

```
{"resourceId": "5293e7fb-ffnksadjfn-7b-abfr185fsa6b", "count": "1", "timeFrom": "2016-01-15T01:35:30.314Z", "timeTo": "2016-01-15T01:35:30.314Z", "sourceId": "card_16m7TaFYUmuhEmVRMoEwnaXa", "notes":"fmaksf"}
```

But I am getting error:

```
"data": "Reservation duration has to be positive."
```

The timeFrom and timeTo have to be in that unicode format. How can I add time to the timeTo parameter? I cannot find what each of the characters stands for. It has to only add and hour or two it cannot add days otherwise I will get a different errror. How can I just add one hour to the timeFrom unicode and place that in the unicode for timeTo to make this pass? I am trying to test other functionality but have to get past this first.

Comment: Is your data originally a dictionary?

Comment: Do you want to just know what the fields are do you can change them manually, or do you actually want to manipulate the data structure with Python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"timeFrom": "2016-01-15T01:35:30.314Z"
"timeTo":   "2016-01-15T01:35:30.314Z"
```

Given they're exactly the same time, the duration will very much be zero (hence non-positive).

---

If you're just interested in knowing the format so you can pass in more appropriate values, the following will help. The components of the time strings are:

```
2016-01-15T01:35:30.314Z
|||| || || || || || ||||                       |
|||| || || || || || |||+- UTC timezone
|||| || || || || || +++-- milliseconds
|||| || || || || ++------ seconds
|||| || || || ++--------- minutes
|||| || || ++------------ hours
|||| || ++--------------- day of month
|||| ++------------------ month
++++--------------------- year
```

So, if you wanted to add an hour (for example), simply pass in:

```
2016-01-15T02:35:30.314Z
```

---

If instead you want to use Python to dynamically modify the string, it's as "simple" as something like:

```
import datetime as dt
str1 = "2016-01-15T01:35:30.314Z"
fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
print(str1)
str2 = (dt.datetime.strptime(str1.replace('Z','000+0000'),fmt) + dt.timedelta(hours=1)).strftime(fmt).replace('000+0000','Z')
print(str2)
```

which outputs for me at this time:

```
2016-01-15T01:35:30.314Z
2016-01-15T02:35:30.314Z
            ^
            note this bit
```

The meat of that is the setting of `str2` which basically boils down to:

- Change the string so that `strptime` will be happy (the first `replace`).
- Use `strptime` to create a `datetime` object.
- Add one hour to that object using a `timedelta` for which you can specify all sorts of durations.
- Turn it back into a string with `strftime`.
- Modify the string to match the original format, with the second `replace`.

Note that this only works with the `Z` timezone specifier, if you want to handle other timezones, you'll need to specify what they are.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `datetime` module to handle datetimes . You can use `datetime.datetime.strptime()` to parse your string as a `datetime.datetime` object , then use `datetime.timedelta` and add the 1 hour you want to it, and then use `datetime.datetime.strftime()` to parse it back to string in the format you want. Example -

```
d['timeTo'] = (datetime.datetime.strptime(d['timeFrom'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ') + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'
```

Demo -

```
>>> d = {"resourceId": "5293e7fb-ffnksadjfn-7b-abfr185fsa6b", "count": "1", "timeFrom": "2016-01-15T01:35:30.314Z", "timeTo": "2016-01-15T01:35:30.314Z", "sourceId": "card_16m7TaFYUmuhEmVRMoEwnaXa", "notes":"fmaksf"}
>>> import datetime
>>> d['timeTo'] = (datetime.datetime.strptime(d['timeFrom'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ') + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'
>>> d['timeTo']
'2016-01-15T02:35:30.314Z'
```

If you are using Python 2.x , you can use `str.decode()` method to decode your string into unicode object , using the encoding you want. In Python 3.x, you get a normal unicode object back, hence there would be no need of decoding it.